# Patching gcc, Adding memory write to a sparc fsqrts insn

Tags: gcc, code-generation

I'd like to patch gcc's sparc machine description so
that the destination register of a FPU sqareroot operation fsqrts
is stored into memory after each fsqrts.

like this:

```
fsqrts %f2,%f4
st %f4, -4[%fp]  <= add this after every fsqrts where -4[%fp] is
                            a slot allocated on the stack for each fsqrts insn
```

The sparc.md portion that defines the fsqrts pattern is:

```
(define_insn "sqrtsf2"
 [(set (match_operand:SF 0 "register_operand" "=f")
       (sqrt:SF (match_operand:SF 1 "register_operand" "f")))]
 "TARGET_FPU"
 "fsqrts\t%1, %0"
 [(set_attr "type" "fpsqrts")])
```

i thought I could add  the "`st %f4, -4[%fp]`" there. But now
my question:

- Where/when/how can I allocate the stackframe slot to save the
  destination fpu reg in (the offset to %fp).

I'm not that familiar with rtl representation and the stages
of compilation. So any help would be apreciated.

Maybe another architecture has a similar construct already
that I could study and use for my purpose. If somebody
can point me to such machine description part ...

Comment: I managed to patch the .md description to issue the extra store,
however now I was wondering about how to avoid beeing scheduled into a  delay slot. Posted the patched .md at (with the scheduleing question):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236424/how-to-avoid-insn-beeing-scheduled-into-a-delay-slot

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve, wouldn't the same thing be easier with some clever re#defining the appropriate C-level functions?

Answer (score 2):

Again, that's a question for gcc@gcc.gnu.org